# Google App script do a check in another googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

In a google sheet - name "birthday2024" - I have the "column M" (Random ID - unique code) and the "column J" which indicates the expiry date of the "RANDOM ID" code.

[image]

Request:

1. With a new google form is it possible to search for a code of the "column M" on the birthday2024 sheet?
2. If yes, I would like you to give me an affirmative answer if the "ramdom-id" is correct and not expired.
   Otherwise if the "random-id" is incorrect or expired or has already been used once, give me a negative answer.

I hope I explained myself better this time.
Thanks everyone for the help.
Mauro

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Example: column M (example: 2024-0awkt) and the code expires after approximately 15 days - Column J (example: 12/27/2023)`. Also, I cannot understand the relationship between your 2 provided images and your goal. Can I ask you about the details of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thanks first of all for the reply.
I would like it possible to search for the same code, if present, from a Google form (img GOOGLE FORM NUMBER2) in another Google sheet (example: 2024-0awkt, as per photo GOOGLESHEET NUMBER1)
See if the code is present and if the code is valid (expiry date 15 days).

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, how do you want to retrieve the search result?

Comment: Not being a programming expert I don't quite understand what you mean.
I would like to do this. From the google form a person enters a code. By clicking on next, a search is made to see if the code exists and if it has not expired. If the result is positive, we continue, if the result is negative (wrong or expired code) an ALLERT message appears!
Possible?

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, about `I don't quite understand what you mean.`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. About `I would like to do this. From the google form a person enters a code. By clicking on next, a search is made to see if the code exists and if it has not expired. If the result is positive, we continue, if the result is negative (wrong or expired code) an ALLERT message appears! Possible?`, I think that this cannot be achieved by Google Form. In that case, I think that HTML form instead of Google Form can be achieved.

Comment: Not being a programmer is not a problem but providing us examples written in an unfamiliar language is.  I've read your question several times and I still don't understand the question.  It's true it could be my problem and not yours but I still cannot provide any assistance to you other than to say I don't understand.

Comment: Excuse me, I'll rephrase the question later to be clearer. Thanks for all your advice.

Comment: I think possibly your question is can you interact programmatically with a google form while it is being filled out and the answer to that question is no.  You must until the form is submitted and then you can interact with the return data.

Comment: I updated the question to try to be more clear. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is not more clear, and the response that @Cooper gave still holds. `With a new google form is it possible to search for a code of the "column M" on the birthday2024 sheet?` **NO**, a form cannot not interact dynamically with a spreadsheet **prior to submission**. OTOH,  **once the form has been submitted** then **YES** you can interact with the submitted data. `If yes`... if the code is a submitted as an answer to a question, then it is possible to establish whether or not the code is expired or not.